# C++ need for Assembly in embedded systems

Tags: c++, c, assembly, embedded

I hear of a need to call assembly functions/calls when programming embedded systems in C. Is this necessary in C++ or not?

Comment: There assembly language functions may not be necessary when programming embedded systems; depends upon the support packages and the performance.  I prefer to replace whole C or C++ functions with assembly functions (in separate files) rather than inline assembly.  Inline assembly is usually reserved for accessing hardware directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ does not provide any more low-level constructs than C does. Hence, if you need to fiddle around with control registers and ISRs in C, you will need to do it in C++.

Comment: I understand that C++ does not provide any lower-level constructs than C. But, what do you mean by "you will need to do it in C++" - the statement sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, I meant that if you _need_ to go down to the level of assembly in C, you will need to do so when using C++ instead. C++ does not offer any advantages in this aspect.

Comment: dirkgently: Got it.
Earlz: I think I was specific enough.

Answer (score 3):

Calling assembly functions or using assembly calls consists of:

- Either- inline assembly wrapped in a C/C++ function using the appropriate compiler tag or
- Another object linked with your executable which was written in assembly that behaves like a C function with respect to the implementation on your system.

So, if you need to use assembly in C, you need to use assembly in C++. That is true not just of embedded programming, too. Take executing the instruction `cpuid` on intel x86 chips as an example.